# How can I increase the frame size of the titles in Adobe Premiere?

Tags: premiere

In Adobe Premiere Pro CC 2015, I did hours of work on a video that is 640x360 pixels.  I added a bunch of "titles" of that same resolution.

Then I later realized that I wanted to export my project at 1920x1080 even though the source video was 640x360.  (At least then my titles would be more legible on high resolution monitors.)

I easily changed the resolution of the video portions of my project, but **how can I change the frame size of the titles?**

I don't want to just "scale" them up to 1920x1080; I want them to actually BE that size and to be clear.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I know, unfortunately you can't take an old title which was based on whatever frame size, and switch its size to something else. The only way I know for your situation with the small titles is:

1. Double click on a title that you want to change (either on the timeline or in the project).
2. In the title editor window, click on the top left button of 'New title based on current title'.

[image: Premiere title editor screen capture]

3. A pop up shows - type in the size you want for the NEW title AND don't forget to check (or change) the name of that new title, just that later on you know which title is which. Click OK.
4. You have just created a new title, you can find it in your project. It has the old text with all its preferences, inside a new size frame; the visual result is the same as you would have got with scaling, but w/o the quality loss.
5. That should do the trick for you, but you'll still have to do it one by one on all the titles, and then to put each one in the appropriate place on the timeline.

I hope that helps. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

The most recent versions of Premiere have a totally new titling and graphics setup. I have found that changing frame size, say from SD to HD, which I have done recently, the titles don't scale at all and are unusable.
I have to remake them for the new frame size. But it is pretty easy to repurpose the graphics for a new frame size. It would be a pain if there were alot of titles. In my workflow I try to do the titles last, when I already know how I am going to output.